# Hyperbolas and Quadrants on Rotation

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Let's assume we have a standard hyperbola. On rotating the hyperbola $45^{\circ}$ clockwise, the new hyperbola should lie in the $2$nd and $4$th quadrant. However, the equation of a parabola rotated $45^{\circ}$ clockwise is $x y=\frac{a^2}{2}$.
This equation shows that LHS must be positive since RHS is positive, therefore $x$ and $y$ must have the same sign, and the hyperbola graph is actually in the $1$st and $3$rd quadrant. 
Why does this happen?

Comment: How did you get that equation? In particular, what is a "standard" hyperbola and how did you rotate it?

Answer (score 1):

Note that for clockwise rotation by $45^{\circ}$,
\begin{align*}
  \begin{pmatrix} x' \\ y' \end{pmatrix} &=
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \cos (-45^{\circ}) & -\sin (-45^{\circ}) \\
    \sin (-45^{\circ}) &  \cos (-45^{\circ})
  \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} \\
  &=
\begin{pmatrix}
   \cos 45^{\circ} & \sin 45^{\circ} \\
  -\sin 45^{\circ} & \cos 45^{\circ}
  \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} \\
  &=
\begin{pmatrix}
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
  -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
  \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} \\
  &=
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{x+y}{\sqrt{2}} \\
    \frac{y-x}{\sqrt{2}}
  \end{pmatrix} \\
  x' y' &= \frac{y^2-x^2}{2} \\
  x' y' &= -\frac{a^{2}}{2}
\end{align*}

which is **negative!!**

So the transformed hyperbola lies on the **Quadrant II and IV**.